# How can I make a category function as a page?

Tags: categories, customization, pages

I apologize if this is a simple question but I'm entirely new to the website-building process. I have no prior experience. That being said, if the answer requires complicated HTML or CSS, then it won't be of any help to me since I have no knowledge in those areas.

Anyway, my question is just as the title suggests. Categories have the posts listed but the category is blank because I have no way of editing it like you can with a page where in a page, you can add media, text, etc. However, with a page the posts don't show up. So is there an effective way of either, being able to edit the category menu like you can with a page or creating pages for the categories and then adding the posts afterwards? I have Beaver Builder, so I can perhaps use the modules for each post and add it at the end of the page? I'm sorry if the question isn't clear.

Comment: This is more of a Beaver Builder post than WordPress post, so you better ask it in the [Beaver Builder Reddit Page](https://www.reddit.com/r/beaverbuilder/). A short answer is: if you also have Beaver Themer, then you may create a BB template and use that template for any Category page. Without Beaver Themer, it's still possible by using some WordPress category editor plugin or by using custom rewrite CODE.

Answer (score 0):

With Beaver Builder, I'd just add another plugin called "Display Posts Shortcode" that will insert your category wherever you'd like. Maybe the following will help:

1. Download the plugin  "Display Posts Shortcode" here: https://wordpress.org/plugins/display-posts-shortcode/
2. Insert the following text on the page where you want display the posts in your category: [display-posts category="*categoryname*"]
3. You can choose to show an excerpt of the post, or the full post with featured image by editing the parameters. More information on the parameters can be found here: https://github.com/billerickson/display-posts-shortcode/blob/master/README.md#parameters

Any edits to the styling of the posts can be made directly in your CSS editor.